# has_many association with scope in Rails will not accept arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have an `Ad` class which has_many messages. I want to be able to do `ad.messages(user)` to get all the messages to a given user on that ad. I currently have

```
has_many :messages, ->(user) { where(to_id: user.id) }
```

But this isn't working and I can't figure out why. Without the scope it works as expected and returns all message, or if I don't have the argument and hard-code a user ID it also works. The code as it is however, gives me  `wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hacking `has_many` makes it not work how it is supposed to do.

You can just define a method on your class

```rb
class Ad
  def messages(user_id)
    Message
      .where(ad_id: self.id)
      .where("to_id = :user_id OR from_id = :user_id", user_id: user_id)
  end
end

# somewhere else

Ad.first.messages(some_user_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameter of `proc` in `has_many` relationship could just be `belongs_to` relationship in `Message`, in your case, it should be `ad`.

You could add some custom filter condtion, i.e. `has_many :messages, ->(ad) { where(ad_name: ad.name) }`

Then you still call `ad.messages`, without an argument.

So if you want to add `user` parameter to `messages`, you could define a [scope](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods/scope) in `Message` instead:

```rb
class Message  
  scope :with_user, ->(user) { where(to_id: user.id) }
end

ad.messages.with_user(user)
```

Comment: Is the information given here (under Scopes) incorrect? https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many

Comment: Hmm okay. Also if I define a scope your way I get "undefined method `with_user'", and I can't work out why that's happening either!

Comment: Oh, sorry again,  actually you should define `with_user` it in `Message` model. And I'm testing `has_many :messages, ->(user) { where(to_id: user.id) }`, it should work.

Comment: That was basically my problem I think,  trying to pass 'user' in an Ad model, it won't let you do that. Have posted my own answer now. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I'm just figured it out too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229831/discussion-between-eux-and-tsvallender).

Answer (score -2):

I believe I've worked out the answer. An argument passed to an association has to be an instance of the model you're in, for example you can only pass ad to an Ad model, not user as I was trying to do. The correct way to achieve my goal is through an extension as below.

```
has_many :messages do
  def user(user)
    where(:to_id => user.id).or(where(:from_id => user.id))
  end
end
```

Comment: This makes `has_many` not work like it should do.

Comment: In what way does it not work as it should?

Comment: Yoy cannot do ´messages << message.new´ just to name one

Comment: @tsvallender to pass arguments you need to use scopes:

Answer (score -2):

I would just make a scope on the messages model.

```rb
class Message < ApplicationRecord
...
  scope :by_user, -> (user_id) {where(to_id: user_id)}
...
end

ad = Ad.find(<Id>)
user = User.find(<ID>)
ad.messages.by_user(user.id)
```

If you want to check both from and to ids, you could modify the scope like:

```rb
scope :by_user, ->(user_id) {
  where("to_id = :user_id OR from_id = :user_id", user_id: user_id)
}
```